# android:windowSoftInputMode='adjustPan' is not working in Rhomobile

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, rhomobile, adjustpan

The default Rhomobile behavior on Android is to resize the WebView when the keyboard shows up. However, I would rather have the iOS behavior where the view is pushed up. Trying to use android:windowSoftInputMode='adjustPan' in my Android Manifest is not working.

Rhomobile 5.0.2
Android SDK 4.4.2
Min API Level 17
Test Device: Android 4.2.2

Screen without keyboard:

[image: Screen without keyboard]

Screen with the keyboard with the default behavior adjustResize (screen gets messed up):

[image]

Screen with the keyboard with adjustPan (textbox is hidden and window cannot be scrolled):

[image]